# Xlib multiple display support

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib, xorg

I want to get display info via Xlib, specifically:

- iterate displays
- get the screen rectangle for each display (relative to the virtual screen - does X11 have the concept of a virtual screen on which physical screens are mapped, similar to Windows and OSX?)
- get the client area rectangle (so screen minus taskbar etc.) for each display

Thanks.

---

Half answer: using `XineramaQueryScreens()` I was able to enumerate displays and get their coordinates in the virtual screen and their sizes. Now how do I get the desktop size, i.e. the size that the windows maximize to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read [_NET_DESKTOP_GEOMETRY](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472717248) (also maybe _NET_DESKTOP_VIEWPORT and _NET_WORKAREA )

Comment: unfortunately all these properties don't work with multiple monitors.

Comment: which wm are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu Unity (10.04) on a Virtualbox with 2 physical screens: `_NET_WORKAREA` gives me the area of the whole virtual screen minus the top and bottom bars (if I put the bottom bar on the right, it doesn't even take _that_ into account anymore - piece of junk)

Comment: as for _NET_DESKTOP_* these again look at the virtual screen as a whole, not at the physical screens as reported by Xinerama.